# How to change collapsible position in panel extjs4?

Tags: extjs4

When I give `collapsible : true` in panel, collapsible icon (up arrow) is showing at the right most side. How I can show it on left side of the panel?

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'New Section',
    height: 275,
    width: 530,
    margin: 3,
    collapsible : true
});
```

after that I am dynamically editing title using `setTitle(text)` method. The title will be changed but the collapsible will not show up. Can any one know what is happening here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.my-panel .x-tool
{
    left: 0 !important;
}
.my-panel .x-panel-header-text-container
{
    padding-left: 18px;
}
```

Demo here http://ext4all.com/post/how-to-change-collapse-tool-position

Comment: The link above appears to be broken.

Comment: This answer is better than the one here below because if you do not add the second css and use a Title for your header, it is overrun by the collapse tool hence rendered unreadable!! Just so you'd know ;-)

Answer (score 4):

To show the collapsible icon on the **left side**, you have to do it with custom CSS like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    collapsible: true,
    cls: 'my-panel'
});
```

And CSS code:

```
.my-panel .x-tool {
    left: 0 !important;
}
```

After you change your Title, is any error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

### We have tool position for that. Just check below header toolPosition :1

```
    Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            title: 'New Section',
            height: 275,
            width: 530,
            margin: 3,
            collapsible : true, 
            header: {
                  titlePosition: 1,
        }
        });
```